# Site Edit in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 giving "Edit is disabled" message for a component

Tags: dd4t, siteedit, 2011-sp1

I have an DD4T website in Tridion 2011 SP1. For a particular component, we are getting "Edit is disabled" message. even though the tags are in place for Site Edit. I am not sure where to start looking as I don't see any miss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of questions on this site about this. In its current state this question is not detailed enough. Please search and spend some time trying to fix the issue before asking on here. Tell us what you tried.

Comment: Probably the Component Template that is linked to the schema that your component is based on is not enabled for Inline Editing. Check the checkbox on the Component Template and try again.

Comment: Albert I guess you should add this as an answer. @guest_14 this still isn't a very good question. You could have found this quite easily by following the Experience Manager / Site Edit documentation or searching here.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the Component Template that is linked to the schema that your component is based on is not enabled for Inline Editing. Check the checkbox and try again